# Google Play Error: SSL Error Handler vulnerabilities and APP UPDATE REJECTED

Tags: google-play, android-security, sslerrorhandler

How to solve below mentioned error from google play store after apk rejected

> Your APK has been rejected for containing security vulnerabilities, which violates the Malicious Behavior policy
>   SSL Error Handler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the rejection message. It will point to the class that is at fault. If you have a `WebViewClient`, then make sure you implement `onReceivedSslError()` method. [Here](https://support.google.com/faqs/answer/7071387) are more details.

Comment: How to implement this please?