# Google play store rejected application due to SSL Error Handler code

Tags: android, google-play, android-webview, android-security, sslerrorhandler

HI All my Google PlayStore Reject my application because below code is in my application.

check [sakiM's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36147896/3778703).

```
@Override
public void onReceivedSslError(WebView view, final SslErrorHandler handler, SslError error) {
    final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setMessage(R.string.notification_error_ssl_cert_invalid);
    builder.setPositiveButton("continue", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            handler.proceed();
        }
    });
    builder.setNegativeButton("cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            handler.cancel();
        }
    });
    final AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
    dialog.show();
}
```

How to fix this error?

**Error mail from play store :** 
Hello Google Play Developer,

We rejected **YOurAPP**, with package name **com.example.myApp**, for violating our [Malicious Behavior](https://play.google.com/about/privacy-security-deception/malicious-behavior/) or [User Data](https://play.google.com/about/privacy-security-deception/personal-sensitive/) policy. If you submitted an update, the previous version of your app is still available on Google Play.

This app uses software that contains security vulnerabilities for users or allows the collection of user data without proper disclosure.

Below is the list of issues and the corresponding APK versions that were detected in your recent submission. Please upgrade your app(s) as soon as possible and increment the version number of the upgraded APK.

**Vulnerability APK Version(s)  Past Due Date**
**SSL Error Handler**For more information on how to address WebView SSL Error Handler alerts, please see this [Google Help Center article](https://support.google.com/faqs/answer/7071387).  12  November 30, 2016

To confirm you’ve upgraded correctly, submit the updated version of your app to the Play Console and check back after five hours to make sure the warning is gone.

While these vulnerabilities may not affect every app that uses this software, it’s best to stay up to date on all security patches. Make sure to update any libraries in your app that have known security issues, even if you're not sure the issues are relevant to your app.

Apps must also comply with the Developer Distribution Agreement and Developer Program Policies.

If you feel we have made this determination in error, please reach out to our developer support team.

Best,

The Google Play Team

Comment: The idea is that you are supposed to examine the `SSLCertificate` inside the `SSLError` and determine if this is indeed a valid certificate for whatever server you are hitting. Then, and only then, do you call `proceed()`.

Comment: @CommonsWare I have valid certificate in website but it's not working on API level 19 , it's throw sslError .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google Play Error: SSL Error Handler vulnerabilities and APP UPDATE REJECTED](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41236517/google-play-error-ssl-error-handler-vulnerabilities-and-app-update-rejected)